# Automorphism of commutative groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, automorphism-group

> For every group G there is a natural group homomorphism G → Aut(G)
>   whose image is the group Inn(G) of inner automorphisms and whose
>   kernel is the center of G. Thus, if G has trivial center it can be
>   embedded into its own automorphism group
>
> The inner automorphism group of a group G, Inn(G), is trivial (i.e.,
>   consists only of the identity element) if and only if G is abelian.

Consider group C4 and Homomorpism f: C4->Aut(C4). Inn(C4)={e}. Ker(f)=Center(C4)={all elements of C4}.

But |Aut(C4)|=()=(4)=2, where () is Euler's function. Aut(C4) is isomorphic to C2. There is quotient map from C4 to C2. |Img(f)| = 2

Can you please suggest where is my mistake?

Comment: Cf. [outer automorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_automorphism_group)

Comment: С2 is outer automorphisms?

Comment: Both the group of outer automorphisms and the group of automorphisms are isomorphic to $C_2$. The fact that they are isomorphic is a consequence of the fact that the group of inner automorphisms is trivial.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @Shaun thank you, will do it right next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two automorphisms of $C_4$, true. But one of them (given by $x\mapsto -x$) isn't an inner / conjugation automorphism, so it is not in the image of $f$. The kernel of $f$ is the center of $C_4$, which is all of it, and the image of $f$ is trivial (it is isomorphic to $C_4/Z(C_4)$, as it should be).

The fact that $\operatorname{Aut}(C_4)$ is (isomorphic to) a quotient of $C_4$ is incidental and not really relevant.